# Logout X Session When Application Closes

Tags: x11, login, logout, twm

I'm setting up X with TWM so that folks here can access one specific graphical application. I have it setup so one can VNC in, log-in using XDM and have said application automatically start up.

What I'd like to do is have it automatically log-out of the session once that application closes. Is there a trick I can do in the xinit script, or find some way to make TWM dependent on this particular application?

Comment: Not sure if this meets your needs exactly, but there is very little magic to logging out of a X11 session. You may want to have a look at for example the source code for `xfce4-session-logout` (it's ever so possible that you might even be able to press that into service directly).

Answer (score 2):

An X session ends when its “main” client process ends. Often that's the window manager; in setups it's a separate session manager process. In your setup, just kill the twm process when the application exits.

If your `.xinitrc` runs `twm` in the background then you can do

```
twm &
myapplication
kill $!
```

If you make twm start your application with `f.exec` then use `f.exec "myapplication; kill $PPID"` instead of `f.exec "myapplication"`.

If you only ever want to display a single application and it only displays a single window then you could just start it full screen instead of the window manager. A window manager isn't much use when there's a single application. This is known as a “kiosk” configuration.